# Failed writing received data to disk/application on libcurl

Tags: c++, visual-studio, curl, libcurl

I'm using VC++ 2015 (v140) with QT MSVC 2015. My project is 32-bit(x86) and libcurl is compiled as is, I mean I just downloaded from official website and compiled it, no OpenSSL or other fancy extensions were added.

The code I'm trying to run is here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <curl/easy.h>
#include <string>

class Essentials {
private:
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

public:
    std::string SSLInternetConnection(char* url) {
        curl = curl_easy_init();
        if (curl) {
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://google.com");
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
            curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
            if (res == CURLE_OK) {
                return "CONNECTED";
            }
            else {
                fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
                return curl_easy_strerror(res);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I'm calling it from a function that creates a dialog, and I'm writing the result to the label in the dialog.

```
#include <QtWidgets/QDialog>
#include <QtWidgets/QMessageBox>
#include <QtWidgets/QSpacerItem>
#include <QtWidgets/QGridLayout>
#include <QtWidgets/QLabel>
#include <DH_loginView.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include "Essentials.cpp"

class Dialogs {
    public:
        void loginDialog(const QString uname, QMainWindow *a) { // this function is where I'm calling the curl lib.
            Ui::loginView loginViewer;
            loginViewer.setupUi(a);
            Essentials e;
            std::string asd = e.SSLInternetConnection("http://google.com/");
            QString aaa = QString::fromStdString(asd);
            loginViewer.label->setText(aaa);
            //QString utf8Dialog = uname + QStringLiteral(" kullanıcısı giriş yapıyor");
            a->setWindowTitle(aaa);
        }
        void loginErr1() {
            QMessageBox mbox;
            QSpacerItem* horizontalSpacer = new QSpacerItem(500, 0, QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
            mbox.setWindowTitle("HATA");
            QGridLayout* layout = (QGridLayout*)mbox.layout();
            layout->addItem(horizontalSpacer, layout->rowCount(), 0, 1, layout->columnCount());
            mbox.setText(QStringLiteral("Kullanıcı adı ve şifre boş olamaz!"));
            mbox.exec();
        }
};
```

And the issue is, http://google.com is reachable on every app on my PC. However, I used to have "Couldn''t resolve hostname" error for a while, and when I turned on my PC today, it was throwing a different error.  I have no idea why is this happening, because I'm working with curl on php for years and I acknowledge that this issue is out of my knowledge, since I'm newbie on C++.

[image: err]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you have the same error with this code sample? Are you using a writeCallback function?

Comment: Check the return code from `curl_easy_perform` and then refer to the docs for what it means...

Comment: BTW you should call curl_global_init before invoking any curl API and ::curl_global_cleanup() on clean up

Comment: @Asesh thanks for the comment. The thing is I've copied the writecallback from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884048/cookies-not-being-saved-in-curl-c-such-a-simple-and-clean-code-example-wont and when I call function twice, it just keeps the old HTML resources.

Comment: BTW you would also want to call curl_easy_getinfo after sending a request to the server with CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE to get the server's response code